# n:m Relation with additional Information in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, entity-relationship

I got a problem with relations in Hibernate.

Scenario: I got 2 Entities ‘Task’ and ‘Resource’. Every ‘Task’ can have multiple ‘Resource’s and every ‘Resource’ can have multiple ‘Task’s. So that the relation is a n:m-Relation.  In the relation table I need an additional column for the type of ‘Resource’ because there are different roles in the ‘Task’ that the ‘Resource’ can have.

I found some examples for join table with extra column and tried to implement it that way. Example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

The problem:
When I delete a ‘Task‘ that has an association with ‘Resource’ an javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: […] is thrown.

Now my question:
Is the ‘join table with extra column’ the best way handle this scenario?  Or is it better to use simple ManyToMany(@JoinTable) Relations for every role that the ‘Resource’ can have?
For example: When there are 4 roles there would be 4 different relation tables between ‘Task’ and ‘Resource’.

What can be the reason for the following exception?

```
‘javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: […]’
```

Edited:

```
deleted entity passed to persist: [com.domain.Task# ]
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1369)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:81)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy43.deleteVorgaenge(Unknown Source)
    com.service.locklayers.TaskLockService.deleteTasks(TaskLockService.java:364)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Here are the involved Classes...

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "task" )
public class Task implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  @Column( name = "task_id" )
  private int         taskId;

  private String      name;

  @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "taskFk", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
  Set<TaskZuResource> taskZuResourceList = new HashSet<TaskZuResource>();

  public int getId()
  {
    return taskId;
  }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "resource" )
public class Resource implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  @Column( name = "resource_id" )
  private int         resourceId;

  private String      name;


  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "resourceFk", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
  Set<TaskZuResource> taskZuResourceList = new HashSet<TaskZuResource>();

  public int getId()
  {
    return resourceId;
  }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "task_zu_resource" )
public class TaskZuResource implements Serializable
{
  @EmbeddedId
  private TaskZuResourceId pk;

  @MapsId( "taskFk" )
  @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
  @JoinColumn( name = "task_fk" )
  private Task                 taskFk;

  @MapsId( "resourceFk" )
  @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
  @JoinColumn( name = "resource_fk" )
  private Resource             resourceFk;

  public TaskZuResource()
  {
  }

  public TaskZuResource( Task taskFk, Resource resourceFk, int resourcenArt )
  {
    this.taskFk = taskFk;
    this.resourceFk = resourceFk;

    pk = new TaskZuResourceId( taskFk.getId(), resourceFk.getId(), resourcenArt );
  }


  public TaskZuResourceId getPk()
  {
    return pk;
  }

  public void setPk( TaskZuResourceId pk )
  {
    this.pk = pk;
  }


  public Task getTaskFk()
  {
    return taskFk;
  }

  public void setTaskFk( Task taskFk )
  {
    this.taskFk = taskFk;
  }

  public Resource getResourceFk()
  {
    return resourceFk;
  }

  public void setResourceFk( Resource resourceFk )
  {
    this.resourceFk = resourceFk;
  }


  @Transient
  public int getResourcenType()
  {
    return getPk().getResourcenType();
  }


  public void setResourcenType( int resourcenArt )
  {
    getPk().setResourcenType( resourcenArt );
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((pk == null) ? 0 : pk.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((resourceFk == null) ? 0 : resourceFk.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((taskFk == null) ? 0 : taskFk.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals( Object obj )
  {
    if ( this == obj )
      return true;
    if ( obj == null )
      return false;
    if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() )
      return false;
    TaskZuResource other = (TaskZuResource) obj;
    if ( pk == null )
    {
      if ( other.pk != null )
        return false;
    }
    else
      if ( !pk.equals( other.pk ) )
        return false;
    if ( resourceFk == null )
    {
      if ( other.resourceFk != null )
        return false;
    }
    else
      if ( !resourceFk.equals( other.resourceFk ) )
        return false;
    if ( taskFk == null )
    {
      if ( other.taskFk != null )
        return false;
    }
    else
      if ( !taskFk.equals( other.taskFk ) )
        return false;
    return true;
  }

}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class TaskZuResourceId implements Serializable
{
  private int taskFk;
  private int resourceFk;

  @Column( name = "resourcen_type" )
  private int resourcenType;

  public TaskZuResourceId()
  {
  }

  public TaskZuResourceId( int taskFk, int resourceFk, int resourcenType )
  {
    this.taskFk = taskFk;
    this.resourceFk = resourceFk;
    this.resourcenType = resourcenType;
  }

  public int getTaskFk()
  {
    return taskFk;
  }

  public void setTaskFk( int taskFk )
  {
    this.taskFk = taskFk;
  }

  public int getResourceFk()
  {
    return resourceFk;
  }

  public void setResourceFk( int resourceFk )
  {
    this.resourceFk = resourceFk;
  }

  public int getResourcenType()
  {
    return resourcenType;
  }

  public void setResourcenType( int resourcenType )
  {
    this.resourcenType = resourcenType;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + resourceFk;
    result = prime * result + resourcenType;
    result = prime * result + taskFk;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals( Object obj )
  {
    if ( this == obj )
      return true;
    if ( obj == null )
      return false;
    if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() )
      return false;
    TaskZuResourceId other = (TaskZuResourceId) obj;
    if ( resourceFk != other.resourceFk )
      return false;
    if ( resourcenType != other.resourcenType )
      return false;
    if ( taskFk != other.taskFk )
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Thx

Comment: Show us the entities, the code which throws this exception, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Here are your desired classes

Comment: when you delete a Task do the Resources also need to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you still have references to a deleted entity. For example, you delete a Task object, but there is still a TaskResource object that references the deleted task.

If this is the problem, then after you delete the Task you can try something like `taskResource.setTaskFk(null)` to remove the dangling reference.

Comment: You brought me on the right way :). I set all Fk-References explicit to null and that was the solution. thx